# Grab the sum of payment amounts from referred users

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a referral system and as a part of that dashboard I need to output the number of referrals a user has received, the total sum of coins they've earned as a result of those referrals purchasing items and finally how many referrals purchased items and the total sum.

For example, showing information for `User_ID` 1:

```
Referrals: 3
Total no. of purchases from all referrals: 2
Sum of purchase amount: $14.00
Coins earned as a result of those purchases: 140 (14 * 10)
```

My table structure is as follows:

**Users**

```
|-------------------------------------------------|
|  id  | ... some other columns ... | referred_by |
|-------------------------------------------------|
|   1  |      ..............        |      0      |
|   2  |      ..............        |      1      |
|   3  |      ..............        |      1      |
|   4  |      ..............        |      1      |
---------------------------------------------------
```

**Purchases**

```
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|  purchase_id  |  user_id  |  payment_status  |  amount  |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|       1       |     2     |     Completed    |  10.00   |
|       2       |     3     |     Completed    |   4.00   |
|       3       |     1     |     Completed    |   9.00   |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

At the moment I am running this query. For some reason, and I cannot get my head around the problem, it grabs the sum of only the first user it matches (`id = 2` in the case of this example). The `count(id) = 3` but the `sum(amount) = 10.00` rather than the expected `14.00`. Any ideas?

```
SELECT count(id) AS count, 
(SELECT COALESCE(sum(amount), 0.00) 
    FROM purchases
    WHERE purchases.user_id = users.id 
    AND payment_status = "Completed" 
) AS purchases_amount, 
(SELECT COALESCE(sum(round(amount) * 10), 0) 
    FROM purchases
    WHERE users.id = purchases.user_id 
    AND payment_status = "Completed"
) AS coins_earned,    
(SELECT count(purchase_id) 
    FROM purchases
    WHERE users.id = purchases.user_id
    AND payment_status = "Completed"
) AS purchases_count
FROM (`users`) 
WHERE `referred_by` = '1' 
AND `created` >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00' // created = user's registration date
AND `created` <= '2015-12-31 23:59:59'
```

Data set returned:

```
count: 3 (expected: 3)
purchases_amount: 10.00 (expected: 14.00)
coins_earned: 100 (expected: 140)
purchases_count: 1 (expected: 2)
```

Comment: This seems like it would benefit from some SQL simplification and `GROUP`ING

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into the MySQL problem where it silently allows aggregates to be combined with non-aggregates without a proper group-by. Other RDBMSes would complain about your query since the `COUNT()` aggregate in your first column conflicts with the multiple rows returned by the rest of the query.

Try removing the first column in the select (`count(id) AS count`) and you will see the query returns one row for each user id (2, 3, and 4).

To fix the problem, sum all of the results of each subquery:

```
SELECT count(id) AS count, 
sum((SELECT COALESCE(sum(amount), 0.00) 
    FROM purchases
    WHERE purchases.user_id = users.id 
    AND payment_status = "Completed" 
)) AS purchases_amount, 
sum((SELECT COALESCE(sum(round(amount) * 10), 0) 
    FROM purchases
    WHERE users.id = purchases.user_id 
    AND payment_status = "Completed"
)) AS coins_earned,    
sum((SELECT count(purchase_id) 
    FROM purchases
    WHERE users.id = purchases.user_id
    AND payment_status = "Completed"
)) AS purchases_count
FROM (`users`) 
WHERE `referred_by` = '1' 
AND `created` >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00' // created = user's registration date
AND `created` <= '2015-12-31 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score -1):

i believe u may try this

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(SUM(amount), 0.00) AS purchases_amount,
    COALESCE(SUM(ROUND(amount) * 10), 0) AS coins_earned,
    COUNT(purchase_id) AS purchases_count
FROM purchases
WHERE
    payment_status = "Completed"     
    AND user_id IN (
        SELECT id FROM users
        WHERE `referred_by` = '1' 
        AND `created` >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00'
        AND `created` <= '2015-12-31 23:59:59'  
    )
```